# Yii2 form inputs adjusting to fillup whole width

Tags: php, html, css, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have this form input that i would like it to fill the whole div with but it fails

```
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-8" >
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(["placeholder"=>
                     "your email address", "width"=>"100%;"])- >label(false)  //this fails 
                       ?>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="submit" name="subscribe"
                         class="nl-submit"  value="JOIN US">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

What do i need to add to the input field as it fails to fit 100%

Comment: try using col-md-10 instead of col-md-8 .

Comment: Even on md-10 it fails

Comment: What do you get when you use `col-md-10`? It should fill whole div. Can you post a screenshot?